# unit testing ava + sinon for api call, one of the stub is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, sinon, ava

I have a test case need to test a function which has 2 upper layer promise functions.
I stub all of these 3 functions, the first 2 works fine, but the last one seems like no working..

```
classD:

const obj1 = require('./classA');
const obj2 = require('./classB');
const obj3 = require('./classC');

const getTeam = () =>{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        obj1.promiseFunc1().then(res1 => {
            if(res1.error){
              reject(res1); 
            }else{
              resolve({Teamid: 1, TeamName: 'goodName'});
            }
    })
}

const getMember = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      obj2.promiseFunc2().then(res2 => {
        if(res2.id.length === 0){
          obj3.promiseFunc3().then(res3 => {
            if(res3.error){
              reject(res3); 
            }else{
              getTeam().then(res => {
                 if(res.error){
                    reject(res);
                  }else{
                   resolve(res);
                  }
              });
            }
        })
      }
   })    
 })
}
```

Below is the test case:

```
Test.js

const obj1 = require('./classA');
const obj2 = require('./classB');
const obj3 = require('./classC');
const obj4 = require('./classD');
const sandbox = require('sinon').createSandbox();

test.serial('test getMember', async (t) => {
  sandbox.restore();
  sandbox.stub(obj2, 'promiseFunc2').resolves({id: [], error: false});
  sandbox.stub(obj3, 'promiseFunc3').resolves({status: 200, error: false});

  sandbox.stub(obj4, 'getTeam').resolves({data: [], error: false});

  const result = await obj4.getMember();
  console.log('result :' + JSON.stringify(result));
})
```

So I need to runa test case for the function obj4.getMember() which will call obj2.promiseFunc2, obj3.promiseFunc3, and obj4.getTeam(), they all return promises. I stub the promiseFunc2 and promiseFunc3 with no problem. But for some reason the obj4.getTeam() seems like not working well. I returned {Teamid: 1, TeamName: 'goodName'} which is the response from last test cases in the same file for getTeam()...

I expected to return {data: [], error: false} which is the outcome I stub for..

Anyone know why the stub is not working? How to make it work?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi, I don't know what's happening but I am worried that you paint yourself into a corner. If you test a codebase that is so coupled, with stubs deeply rooted in its internals, you will make your tests fragile, discourage refactoring and progressively loose control of your code, which is what testing is suppose to prevent... Your test is also difficult to parse because your code is difficult to test. If I have one advice: don't test this code, refactor it, make it easy to test. And also learn how to chain Promises and how to use `Promise.reject`. If you have time...

Comment: Thanks for replying! Unfortunately, the code has been working for a very long time...I don't think my manager will allow me to change the code...:(

Answer (score 1):

Calling `getTeam` as a function from `obj4.getMember` could be bypassing Simon's stub.

Try the following:

```
const obj1 = require('./classA');
const obj2 = require('./classB');
const obj3 = require('./classC');

const obj4 = {};

obj4.getTeam = () =>{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        obj1.promiseFunc1().then(res1 => {
            if(res1.error){
              reject(res1); 
            }else{
              resolve({Teamid: 1, TeamName: 'goodName'});
            }
        })
    })
}

obj4.getMember = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      obj2.promiseFunc2().then(res2 => {
        if(res2.id.length === 0){
          obj3.promiseFunc3().then(res3 => {
            if(res3.error){
              reject(res3); 
            }else{
              obj4.getTeam().then(res => {
                 if(res.error){
                    reject(res);
                  }else{
                   resolve(res);
                  }
              });
            }
        })
      }
   })    
 })
}
        
module.exports = obj4;
```

I don't think you should call modules "classes" as it sets wrong expectations.

---

As for Promise chaining, it is unfortunate your API does not reject on errors, which forces you to add a lot of error handling logic, but a helper could convert these promises to rejected promises

```
const rejectOn = predicate => f => (...xs) =>
    f(...xs).then(x => predicate(x) ? Promise.reject(x) : x);

const error = x => x.error;
```

With this in place, the following would be easier to read and functionally identical (assuming `objN.promiseFuncN` are not methods with a context). Note that there is no need to wrap a promise-returning function in a new Promise and that returning a Promise replaces the surrounding Promise, removing a lot of boilerplate from your code.

```
obj4.getTeam = () => 
    rejectOn(error)(obj1.promiseFunc1)()
    .then(() => ({ Teamid: 1, TeamName: 'goodName' }));


obj4.getMember = () =>
    rejectOn(x => x.id.length)(obj2.promiseFunc2)()
    .then(rejectOn(error)(obj3.promiseFunc3))
    .then(rejectOn(error)(obj4.getTeam));
```

Maybe you should have a talk with your manager. Clean code does not slow you down. Rotting code slows you down.

Comment: Thank you for answering! Can you show how the test case code should be? I tried to put on a obj4 = {} in the js file. The the ava says: cannot stub non-existent property of obj4.getTeam ..

Comment: That is weird. In which file did you try to add `obj4 = {}`? Did you also add `obj4.getTeam` and `obj4.getMember` ? Also note that in my original answer I forgot to replace `getTeam` by `obj4.getTeam` in `obj4.getMember` in the first code block. I edited my answer. Note that your test code should not have to change (apart from adding an actual assertion because it's currently not testing anything)